# how to perform 301 redirection for sub pages?

Tags: php

I want to perform 301 redirection for every pages in my site.
Home page I did redirection,But for sub pages I can't able to perform the same thing
I tried this

I have these URLs

```
liyyas.com/newcollections/tops
liyyas.com/newcollections/shorts
liyyas.com/newcollections/pants



   if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'liyyas.com/newcollections')
        {
          Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
          Header( "Location: http://www.liyyas.com/newcollections" );   
        }
```

for performing 301 redirection I want to check only liyyas.com/ upto this but $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] will take full URL So instead of using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] can I pass any other variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want pure PHP try to add this to every sub page

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'liyyas.com')
{
  Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
  Header( "Location: http://www.".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.liyyas.com/newcollections/ [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use APACHE ?
I know you can do it using the .htaccess if your using Apache. Just add the following line to it and all 301 errors will be redirected to your homepage

```
ErrorDocument 301 'mysamplepage.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```